# How do you define private instance variables in Kotlin?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

So im trying to define a private class in kotlin/android studio. Am not sure what is going on, but i tried searching up videos on how to create a private class on kotlin. I stil don't think I know what to do. Any help?

````
package com.example.calculator

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private EditText display            <line of code that is highlighted in red.

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


    }

    public fun zeroBTN(args: View) {

    }

}
[enter image description here][1]```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kY6q7.png
````

Comment: Instead of searching videos, your first step should be to read the first few pages of official documentation on the Kotlin web site. It explains all the syntax and basic behavior clearly and succinctly.

Comment: `private EditText display` is Java syntax (and would work in Java) so maybe you're looking at the wrong tutorials?

Answer (score 2):

That's not how to define variables in Kotlin. You probably want something like this:

```
private lateinit var display: EditText
```